# At which level of voltage is USB device disconnected

Tags: usb

I have to realize a USB switch on my own. For security I have a chip (TPS2052) which has  short - circuit protection and is controlling the current. My problem is:

When I switch from one USB port to another the TPS2052 chip has a delay (ms range) until it goes from 5V to 0V. I have to do some testing with my USB switch circuit. So I have to know exactly when the USB device is disconnected. Can you tell me at which level of voltage the USB device is disconnected?

This shows a diagram. Yellow: Signal that USB device should be disconnected (= Data is also disconnected at this moment) Blue: Supply voltage of the USB port. So can I say when Data is disconnected it doesn't matter that there is still some voltage?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a diagram of how everything is connected? At the moment I can't understand the problem, if you post an image somewhere and post a link in a comment someone will be able to add it to the question.

Comment: http://www.imgbox.de/show/img/OBPRMRVYg7.png
This shows a diagramm. 
Yellow: Signal that USB - Device should be disconnected (= Data is also disconnected at this moment)
Blue: Supply Voltage of the USB.
So can I say: When Data is disconnected, it doesn't matter that there is still some voltage?

Answer (score 1):

Trick question: USB device connection depends on the *data lines*, and not at all on the power. Most devices are bus-powered, and will switch off once their internal capacitors run out of charge, but some are self-powered and will run quite happily with the power line disconnected.

Comment: This isn't *entirely* true. Some devices are poorly designed, and rely on powercycling to reset the local device (or if they're self-powered, use the presence of UCB-Vcc to trigger a local-reset). These devices will not properly reconnect if the data connection is broken and re-established. For these devices, you have to cycle both signal lines **and** power to get them to properly reconnect.

Comment: Any device that automates hot-swapping USB connections should therefore also sequence the disconnection and reconnection of the power as well.

Comment: @ConnorWolf, that seems unlikely. Cycling the data lines will cause USB reset to be signaled from the host -- something that generally happens multiple times during the enumeration process. A device that would ignore USB reset would have troubles connecting in the first place.

Comment: I have previously built a product that has a USB switching function to allow connection of a USB thumb drive to one of two selected computers. I can tell you from practical experience that it is essential to switch the data signal lines AND to cycle the power of the device being switched. It must be done in the right sequence and with enough time delay between steps to ensure that the two host computers can properly track the connect and disconnects of the device.

Comment: And....note that the time delays involved are way shower than a few milliseconds per step. More like in the 100's of milliseconds per step.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, I know that the time delay between switching power and switching data signal lines must be at least 100ms. Is there also a required time delay between switching data off and time off?

Comment: So can I say, when data signal line is switched off, the USB - device isn't connected anymore to the PC?

Comment: I don't think the contact length difference can be counted on to give 100ms delay in intended operation.  And mini/micro connectors seem to have no length difference.